# Работа с сокетами вне локальной сети

Tags: c++, winapi, udp, winsock, сетевое-программирование

Я пишу UDP клиент-сервер. В локальной сети всё работает, но если запустить клиент и сервер на разных компьютерах - отправка идёт успешно, но сокет не принимает пакеты. Если кинуть пакет себе, то на 127.0.0.1 или 192.168.x.x(адрес модема в локальной сети, при каждом запуске он разный) доходит, а если кинуть на свой ip в интернете - нет. Я прочитал и проверил всё много раз, в моём классе нет ошибок, там как в простейших примерах, да и в локальной сети работает же. Я пытался кинуть другу, он открыл и пробросил порт, у нас обоих полностью вырублен брандмауер - не доходит. Видно я чего-то не знаю, так как когда я пытался изучать boost asio, была в точности такая же проблема. Скажите пожалуйста, люди добрые, как достучаться до сокета на другом компьютере?

Comment: Наверное вы работаете под NAT

Comment: Во всех гайдах про UDP клиент-сервер сказано, что нужно просто заполнить структуру адресом и портом, на который нужно кинуть пакет, а на сервере просто создать сокет с этим же портом, и пакет при получении встанет в очередь сообщений. Я понятия не имею, что нужно ещё сделать, объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Почитайте про [NAT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT). Для  выхода из под него делают так называемый "проброс портов" на роутере. Как конкретно это делать, я не знаю. Думаю, в сети есть много инструкций

Comment: Проблема в том, что у меня интернет раздаётся с телефона на ноутбук, поэтому роутера просто нет. Вы можете сказать, что в таком случае сделать это невозможно, нельзя сделать сервер с интернетом через телефон. Но в UDP в отличии от TCP нет соединений, в UDP клиент также ловит сообщения на сокет, как и сервер от клиента, т.е технически нет никакой разницы между клиентом и сервером, как тогда программы устанавливают UDP соединение в автоматическом режиме?

Comment: Ваш телефон в данном случае работает как первичный роутер. Далее он выходит на провайдера, который наверняка использует NAT. UDP или TCP в данном случае разницы нет, адреса в NAT меняются во всех пакетах. Попробуйте описать всю вашу схему соединений в вопросе. Возможно, кто-то более компетентный в практических аспектах сети, нежели я, сможет дать вам ценные советы.

Comment: Спасибо за ваши ответы, я почитаю про NAT.

Comment: Боюсь, что в вашем случае, для полноты картины придется еще и  с сотовой связью (телефон работает по ней) ознакомиться.

Comment: Ваша проблема также еще и в том, что вы находитесь за двойным NAT. Сначала работает NAT в телефоне, а потом еще NAT сотового оператора - так как все телефоны имеют серые IP

Comment: У друга (он же принимающая сторона, сервер) тоже телефонный режим? IP у его роутера белый? Проброс настроен верно? Попробуйте к нему обратиться чем-то другим, каким-нибудь телнетом на какой-то включенный у него сервис - просто чтоб убедиться, что эту часть он настраивает правильно...

Comment: У него роутер, ip белый. Он говорит, что проверял пррброс, я в этом ничего не понимаю.